# Silverlight - Exposing child template dependency properties

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I have created a custom silverlight template control which contains two parts, a ContentControl, and an ItemsControl. I've succesfully created a template which works with them inside the custom template control, but I would like to expose the internal templates of the parts to Blend, so they can be edited, and exposed with the default values.

I've tried various variations of the following code in an attempt to get this to work, but no success.

```
    [TemplatePart(Name = ExpanderTemplateControl2.PartName_FullViewItem, Type = typeof(ExpanderFullViewItem))]
[TemplatePart(Name = ExpanderTemplateControl2.PartName_ItemsControl, Type = typeof(ItemsControl))]
public class ExpanderTemplateControl2 : Control
{
    public const string PartName_FullViewItem = "PART_FullViewItem";
    public const string PartName_ItemsControl = "PART_ItemsControl";

    #region Parts

    private ContentControl part_FullViewItem;
    private ItemsControl part_ItemsControl;

    #endregion


    static ExpanderTemplateControl2()
    {
        //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListControl)));

        //Add Ownership of dependency property
        ItemTemplateProperty = ItemsControl.ItemTemplateProperty;//.AddOwner(typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2));
        ItemsPanelProperty = ItemsControl.ItemsPanelProperty;//.AddOwner(typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2));
        FullViewTemplateProperty = ContentControl.TemplateProperty;//.AddOwner(typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2));
    }

    public ExpanderTemplateControl2()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2);
    }


    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty;
        //= DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsPanelProperty;
        //= DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsPanel", typeof(ItemsPanelTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FullViewTemplateProperty;
        //= DependencyProperty.Register("FullViewItemTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion



    #region Properties

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public ItemsPanelTemplate ItemsPanel 
    {
        get { return (ItemsPanelTemplate)GetValue(ItemsPanelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsPanelProperty, value); }
    }

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public ControlTemplate FullViewTemplate
    {
        get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(FullViewTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FullViewTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Cheers

Tristan

UPDATE: I've managed to get it in a sort of working state by doing the following, but i'm not happy about it. Is there a better way?

```
        #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsPanelProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsPanel", typeof(ItemsPanelTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FullViewTemplateProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("FullViewTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(ExpanderTemplateControl2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get 
        {
            var result = (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);

            if (result == null)
            {
                SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, part_ItemsControl.ItemTemplate);
                result = part_ItemsControl.ItemTemplate;
            }

            return result; 
        }
        set 
        {
            part_ItemsControl.ItemTemplate = value;
            SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public ItemsPanelTemplate ItemsPanel
    {
        get 
        { 
            var result = (ItemsPanelTemplate)GetValue(ItemsPanelProperty);

            if (result == null)
            {
                SetValue(ItemsPanelProperty, part_ItemsControl.ItemsPanel);
                result = part_ItemsControl.ItemsPanel;
            }

            return result; 
        }
        set 
        {
            part_ItemsControl.ItemsPanel = value;
            SetValue(ItemsPanelProperty, value);
        }
    }

    [BindableAttribute(false)]
    public ControlTemplate FullViewTemplate
    {
        get 
        {
            var result = (ControlTemplate)GetValue(FullViewTemplateProperty);

            if (result == null)
            {
                SetValue(FullViewTemplateProperty, part_FullViewItem.Template);
                result = part_FullViewItem.Template;
            }

            return result; 
        }
        set 
        {
            part_FullViewItem.Template = value;
            SetValue(FullViewTemplateProperty, value); 
        }
    }

    #endregion
```